# Phonegap cordova android 4.4 FileTransfer upload SSL not working

Tags: android, file, cordova, upload, transfer

got a problem with the filetransfer upload in cordova for android...

i want to upload any type of file.. means images, videos, sounds..

the problem is, that i don´t know how to get the type/ending of the file (for example .jpg), because with options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1); i only get the location but not the filename with the given type/ending..
i could of course just add + ".jpg" but that won´t help with all other files except of images..
that´s when i choose a file from the photogallery.. when i choose a file from the sd-card nothing happens -> must be a problem with the destination uri

that´s my code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhotoorfile, function(message) {

}, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA  
    });


function uploadPhotoorfile(imageURI) {


var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
};

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var params = new Object();
options.params = params;


var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://domain....com/doupload.php"), win, fail, options, true); 

}



function win(r) {
console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
console.log("Response = " + r.response);
console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
alert("Success");
}

function fail(error) {
alert("Failed" + error.code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code ensure that you return the MIME type as a header

```
<?php
  // open the file in a binary mode
  $name = './images/xyz.png';
  $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

  // send the right headers
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

  // dump the picture and stop the script
  fpassthru($fp);
  exit;
 ?>
```

If the client side needs to have a .jpeg extension, make your URL something like `'https://domain....com/myfile.jpg` and then on the server perform URL rewriting that maps the URL to call your PHP page.